# Multiple threads waiting on an event or condition

Tags: windows, windows-services

In windows driver, I need multiple threads to wait on something and when I get an IOCTL from the user mode , I need to wake up all the waiting threads.

Thank you for any suggestions.
Jacob

Comment: What IRQL are the threads involved running at?

Comment: (and, what version(s) of Windows?)